# Qt - Does a derived class inherit its base class's meta properties?

Tags: qt, qmetaobject

I am working with Qt and came across class hierarchies where a base class (sometimes an abstract class) contains Q_PROPERTY macros; will a derived class inherit each Q_PROPERTY from its base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will. You can easily check this in your debugger: just set a breakpoint after the view / scene is there and inspeckt one of your QObject-instances. You can access the meta-data and the private data for your object and from your base class.

Comment: It didn't for me. I either had to call `QMetaObject::superClass()` or restate the `Q_PROPERTY` macro for each property I wanted in my derived classes.

Comment: I observed different behaviour in debug and release mode! With Qt 5.9.4 every base class inherits each Q_PROPERTY, but in release mode I have to restate them. Really strange!